# Can I use a valve to split a gas line to two appliances?

Tags: gas

We have a gas insert in our fireplace using a 1/2" line. The line used to feed a garage heater but the fireplace took it over.  Can we install a valve that would be used to direct the gas flow to a specific appliance shutting off the other one, so we could run either one separately while the other is turned off? This would run one appliance at a time--never both at the same time.

Comment: That may not actually be necessary. There are tables/formulas/calculators to determine how many BTU can be provided (technically "how much gas volume", but usually expressed as BTU so you can compare it to the requirements of your appliances) by a given size of pipe. It gets complicated - 1" from meter to a junction and then 1/2" for 3 feet after that junction is different from 1/2" for 30 feet. Etc. But you may actually be 100% fine "as is".

Comment: What are the sizes (generally listed in BTU in the US) of your garage heater and your fireplace insert?

Answer (score -1):

You sure could.
For instance, using one of these:
[https://www.amazon.com/DERNORD-Mounting-Stainless-Female-Locking/dp/B07G72DFVQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G72DFVQ)

Comment: -1 Sorry, but recommending a random "Ships from Amazon, sold by randomgibberish" made in China item with no indication of safety is a really, **REALLY** bad idea for anything to be permanently installed in the electric or gas department.